# Derivation Of Mean-Squared Prediction Error For Lognormal Kriging

Tags: logarithms, normal-distribution, regression

[image]

I wonder how that equation was derived from $$E(\varepsilon(s_0))^2=\mu_\varepsilon^2(exp(\sigma^2_Y) -1)$$
for $\varepsilon=Z(s_0)-\hat p_Z(Z;s_0)$ and $Y=log \varepsilon$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Maybe it's only about exponential properties, but I still didn't have a clue to derive $-1$ to $exp(var(\hat p_Y(z;s_0)))-2exp(cov(Y(s_0),\hat p_Y(Z;S_0)))$

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to figure out my answer.
Let's say $Y=\ln Z$ and $\hat p_Y=\ln \hat p_Z$.

$E(Z(s_0))=v_Z$ and $E(\hat p_Z)=v_(\hat p_Z)$

$$E(Z(s_0)-\hat p_Z(Z;s_0))^2=\sigma_Z^2-2cov(Z,\hat p_Z)+var(\hat p_Z)
$$
$$=v_Z^2(exp(\sigma_Y^2)-1)-2v_Zv_(\hat p_Z)(exp(\sigma_(Y\hat p_Y)-1)+v^2_(\hat p_Z)(exp(var(\hat p_Y))-1)$$

To satisfy unbiasedness assumption, so $E(Z(s_0)=E(\hat p_Z(Z;s_0))=v$.
$$E(Z(s_0)-\hat p_Z(Z;s_0))^2=v^2(exp(\sigma_Y^2)-1)-2v^2(exp(\sigma_(Y\hat p_Y)-1)+v^2(exp(var(\hat p_Y))-1)$$
$$=v^2(exp(\sigma_Y^2)-1-2exp(\sigma_(Y\hat p_Y)+2+exp(var(\hat p_Y))-1)$$
$$=v^2(exp(\sigma_Y^2)-2exp(\sigma_(Y\hat p_Y)+exp(var(\hat p_Y)))$$
$$=(exp(2\mu_Y+\sigma^2_Y(s_0))^2(exp(\sigma_Y^2)-2exp(\sigma_(Y\hat p_Y)+exp(var(\hat p_Y)))$$